# Prime number density related to constant density sequences

Tags: prime-numbers, regression, ratio

I'm a student in Calculus BC, and I was thinking about the density of the primes. I wanted to compare the prime series to other series that are the same density throughout, i.e. multiples of 2, 3, or 4. I created a spreadsheet with the first 100,000 primes, and compared the prime numbers $p_n$ with multiples of $kn$, where k is a natural number, for instance 2. I was interested in the ratio between the 2 sequences, so I looked at $p_n/kn$.

When I graphed $kn$ vs. $p_n/kn$, the result was a logarithmic curve. I looked at the logarithmic regression equation for many of the graphs, and they all had a similar coefficient in front of the $ln(x)$: $3/ke$, where $k$ is the multiple being used in the sequence. The pattern holds up to $k=24$, so I'm fairly certain this is a legitimate discovery.

I haven't been able to figure out the y-intercept for the equations yet, but they have a pattern too. Is there any explanation for why this pattern of $3/ke$ exists?

Comment: Your $k$ is a red herring. If $\frac{p_n}{kn}\sim \frac{3\ln n}{ke}$ holds for one $k$, it holds for all $k$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I understand that, but where does the 3 come from? Is there some inherent quality of $p_n/n$ that 3 comes from?

Comment: A consequence of the Prime Number Theorem is that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {p_n}{n\ln n}=1$ although $p_n\approx n(\ln n+\ln \ln n)$ is usually a better approximation.